# How to convert a Django UUID to integer within a queryset annotate?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, uuid

I'm trying to convert UUIDs to integers within an annotate.

So like:

```
Item.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True).annotate(
    int_of_pk=int('pk')
)
```

which throws error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pk'`

or like:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

Item.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True).annotate(
    int_of_pk=Cast('pk', output_field=IntegerField())
)
```

which throws error:

```
File "/path/ve/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce: cannot cast type uuid to integer
LINE 1: ...em"."uuid", ("item"."uuid")::integer ...
                                      ^
```

Any ideas pop out at you?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to do this in an annotation and can't do the conversion afterwards?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes. The integer that results will be converted to a string and then a string comparison will take place with the aim of returning the matching object. This operation will happen a lot and the annotation will be faster. Thanks for thinking about it!